# Select data from each row query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

for example i have transaction table

```
id_transaction|description|id_operator
1             |foo        |21
2             |fooo       |21
1             |oof        |20
```

and the operator table like this

```
id_operator|operator_name
20         |op1
21         |op2
```

how can i query how much transaction that has operator id 20 and 21? i want to retrieve data something like this

```
id_operator|count
20         |1
21         |2
```

i tried this query

```
select count(*) from "transaction" where id_operator in (
    select id_operator from "operator" where "operator_name" like 'op%'
);
```

and this query

```
select count(DISTINCT(trt.id_operator)) from "transaction" trt
join "operator" mso on trt.id_operator = mso.id_operator
and mso."operator_name" like 'op%';
```

but these queries return all data from op1 and op2..and not for each operator..
how can i achieve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. `distinct (trt.id_operator)` is the same as `distinct trt.id_operator`

Comment: Hint: use `GROUP BY`

Comment: @HoneyBadger yes, group by does the job.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `GROUP BY` clauses.

For your case i think you would need

```
select id_operator,count(id_transaction)
from "transaction"
group by id_operator
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`

```
select mso.operator_name,count(trt.id_operator) 
FROM transaction trt
INNER JOIN operator mso on trt.id_operator = mso.id_operator
GROUP BY mso.operator_name;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ddcc1/2)

Comment: He does not need to join, all his operator ids are in the same table ( 1-1 )

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @MKougiouris The OP need to get the `count` by `operator.operator_name`

Comment: @D-Shih he is explicit about wanting data like this:
id_operator|count
20         |1
21         |2

but maybe i missed something!